# parsing SOAP response with touchXML - a problem

Tags: iphone, xcode, touchxml

i've another problem with obj-c: 
i'm trying to parse this XML :

here's the case:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <GetMyDashboardResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <GetMyDashboardResult>
                <MyDashboard>
                    <Profile>Speed Seeker</Profile>
                    <UserID>6</UserID>
                    <VenueName>Prasowa</VenueName>
                    <FriendsCount>10</FriendsCount>
                    <FollowingCount>11</FollowingCount>
                    <FollowersCount>12</FollowersCount>
                    <StatusMessage>aaa</StatusMessage>
                    <StatusDate>2010-08-04T11:38:09.733</StatusDate>
                    <CheckedInTimeStamp>2010-07-30T13:48:24</CheckedInTimeStamp>
                </MyDashboard>
            </GetMyDashboardResult>
        </GetMyDashboardResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

and here's how i'm trying to accomplish it:

```
NSMutableArray *res = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

CXMLDocument *doc = [[[CXMLDocument alloc] initWithData:XMLData options:0 error:nil] autorelease];

NSArray *nodes = NULL;
nodes = [doc nodesForXPath:@"//MyDashboard" error:nil];

for (CXMLElement *node in nodes) 
{
      NSMutableDictionary *item = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
      int counter;
      for(counter = 0; counter < [node childCount]; counter++) 
      {
            [item setObject:[[node childAtIndex:counter] stringValue] forKey:[[node childAtIndex:counter] name]];
      }
      [item setObject:[[node elementsForName:@"Profile"] stringValue] forKey:@"profileName"];  // <------ this magical arrow is pointing to the area of interest
    NSLog(@"petla");
      [res addObject:item];
      [item release];
}

NSLog(@"%@", res);
[res release];
```

`

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

`[node elementsForName]` will return `NSArray`, so you definitely can't use `stringValue` on that. Create temporary `NSArray`, set `elementsForName` to it, check if its object count > 0, take `objectAtIndex:0` and you're good to go!